# Cakephp Call to Undefined Method Set::numeric()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am attempting to port a PHP website into cakePHP which is proving somewhat difficult due to a ridiculous amount of incorrectly named columns in the database tables etc. etc.

Anywho, I've gotten most of the way there after renaming many things,and I can bake the entire site without much issue. I can then browse the site normally (the baked version) and everything seems to work on the face of things however there is a **table called 'sets'** and it seems to cause a problem.

Is there some special reservation for this table name? The issue comes when attempting to utilise the sets controller, ie: site/sets/index or site/sets/add will just return an error saying that it is not defined in the controller, it is.
If I then proceed to access any of the other controllers I am met with this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Set::numeric() in /pathtocake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php on line 2215
```

I then usually have to restart mamp to continue!

Can anyone shed any light on this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set`/`sets` is a protected name for a table and a class. See http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/msg/8d149a246d46d3cf?pli=1 and http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/sajt/2007/02/25/cake-conventions

Rename your table to something like `mysets`.

You can test your schema easily on http://cakeapp.com. This online tools helps you with naming tables correctly and offers cake valid names when a protected name was found.

Answer (score 1):

there is cake class Set - therefore you can't have such a model:

@see http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/f0ef41f705299815/8d149a246d46d3cf for details
although pretty old most of it is still true

Comment: I suspected this, but wanted to confirm before I went through the rigmarole of changing yet more tables and columns..thanks!